# GWT - No source code is available for type 'XXX'; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Tags: gwt, serialization

I am new at GWT and I have an application which has the following class:

```
package evaluation.system.shared;

import java.io.Serializable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

public class Evaluation implements Serializable, IsSerializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String evaluatorRID;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private double score;

    public Evaluation() {
    }

    public String getEvaluatorRID() {
        return evaluatorRID;
    }
    public void setEvaluatorRID(String evaluateeRID) {
        this.evaluatorRID = evaluateeRID;
    }
    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }
    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }
    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }
    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }
    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(double score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    public Evaluation(String evaluatorRID, String fName, String lName,
            double score) {
        this.evaluatorRID = evaluatorRID;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.score = score;
    }
  }
```

and each time I run the application the get the following error:

> [ERROR] [evaluationsystem] Line 10: No source code is available for
>   type evaluation.system.shared.Evaluation; did you forget to inherit a
>   required module?

And as you can see line 10 is the beginning of the class.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Does the file xxx.gwt.xml is on path "evaluation.system" ? Do you have have <source path='shared'> in it ? Also you don't need to implements IsSerializable.

Comment: Yes and Yes. You are right I don't need it but I was trying to see if it was causing the issue (as some people did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found what the problem is, basically its the class name. I am not sure if GWT was unable to recognize the class Evaluation.java because "evaluation" is also in the package name...

All I know is that it occured to me that this could be causing the problem and when I changed the name it worked perfectly!